# What kind of pagination crystal report uses?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

**Here we are talking about inbuilt pagging of crystal report.**

which type of pagination will be in action when i click on previous or next button on report viewer??

1) load only that much data that is need to be shown?

or

2) load all the data and show only what is need to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CR loads all data for main report first. Then, while rendering, it loads all subreports data, required up to current page display. For pagination this means that next page navigation may query data for subreports, previous page uses cached data always. CR actually needs to render all pages up to current to know, where to place page breaks.

This is empirical evidence only - it could be possible that for some kind of reports or environments CR starts rendering before all data is read, but I haven't seen that yet :) Our reports usually include some nasty grouping and similar, which for example requires all data already present in report header or every page footer (pages count, totals etc). We are using "desktop" version of CR engine+viewer, maybe web server engine behaves differently.

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report builds the whole document, you can see it in the page numbering. Another technical reason, that CR can use forward only cursors that makes back paging impossible, it must load the data into the memory.

Comment: what exactly did you mean by "back paging is impossible in CR" ?

Comment: I didn't stated that. If CR would NOT store the whole data or the whole document, it wouldn't be able to step back to a previous page when using such cursors (you can use a cursor as a datasource in Oracle). But you can page back in this documents to, so CR must store the data.